# Value binding on a slider don't update properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

the application I am currently working is controlling the position within a QuickTime movie with a normal NSSlider. Just as in every media player out there.

I wanted to bind the value of the slider to the movie position ( which is in a 0 to 1 range ) to avoid sticky / glue code.

When I drag the slider in the UI, the right setter get called, but for some reason the slider doesn't get updated when I change the value programmatically.
I would say that I understand the principles of bindings and how KVC works. And I also know that you have to either use getters or setters or you have to notify the observers with [self willChangeValueForKey:@"theKey"] and [self didChangeValueForKey:@"theKey"] when you change the values programmatically.

For some reason this still doesn't work.
I also have some log statements in the getter. It isn't even called once!

I can't really explain myself what the reason for this behavior might be.
The only thing, that's a bit different from simple examples found online ( and in Aaron Hillegass's book ) is that I am using a key path instead of a simple key.

From IB, I go to the App Delegate, which has an activeMovie property. The activeMovie is an instance of class VS_Movie which has a moviePosition property. So my keypath is : self.activeMovie.moviePosition which Xcode also seems to find.

I would be grateful for any tips and help provided!
Thanks in advance

Here's some code I am using :

### 1. Property declaration

```
// ivar
NSNumber* _moviePosition;

// Property
@property (retain) NSNumber* moviePosition;
```

### 2. Getter and setter implementation

```
- (NSNumber*) moviePosition
{
    NSLog(@"MoviePosition returned : %lf", [_moviePosition doubleValue]);
    return _moviePosition;
}

- (void) setMoviePosition:(NSNumber*)newPos
{
    NSLog(@"New MoviePosition : %lf", [newPos doubleValue]);

    if ( _moviePosition && [newPos isEqualToNumber:_moviePosition] )
        return;

    if ( _moviePosition ) 
       [_moviePosition release];

    _moviePosition = [newPos retain];

    if ( _positioningReady )
    {
        _positioningReady = NO;

        TimeValue newMovieTime = (TimeValue)([_moviePosition doubleValue] * 
                                             (double)_clipDurationTimeValue);
        SetMovieTimeValue(_qtMovie, newMovieTime);
        [_movieView displayCurrentFrameOfMovie:self];

        // Post a notification to inform the observing 
        // classes so they can do the neccessary handling.
        NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc postNotificationName:VS_MoviePositionChangedNotification 
                      object:self];
    }
}
```

### 3. Calling function

```
- (void) setTimeValue:(TimeValue) value withTimeScale:(TimeScale) scale
{
    SetMovieTimeValue(_qtMovie, value);
    SetMovieTimeScale(_qtMovie, scale);

    double newMoviePosition = (double)GetMovieTime(_qtMovie, NULL) / (double)_clipDurationTimeValue;
    [self setMoviePosition:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:newMoviePosition]];

    [_movieView displayCurrentFrameOfMovie:self];
}
```

Comment: The key path should not start with "self.", but I don't know that that's the problem. Show the property declarations and, if not synthesized, the implementations for both `activeMove` in the app delegate class and `moviePosition` in the `VS_Movie` class. Also, which are you actually using, setters or `-will/DidChangeValueForKey:`? If the latter, show the code which does that. Is the position being updated on a background thread? Finally, why are you not using the built-in movie player/controller views?

Comment: I am building an application for professional use. The built-in movie player/controller views just don't offer the things I need. Will update the post and add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the property is called `moviePosition`, the getter should be called `-moviePosition` (no underscore) and the setter should be called `-setMoviePosition:` (no underscore and the first letter of the property name capitalized).

You didn't show the `@property` declaration. While it is allowed to specify the names of the setter and the getter, neither KVC nor KVO pay attention to that. For them, it needs to follow the naming conventions. See [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide: Accessor Search Patterns for Simple Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA).

Are you sure the right setter is being called as you claim? Because you have misnamed your accessor methods, the compiler doesn't recognize them as such. Therefore, the `@synthesize` is generating properly named ones. Those are being invoked by KVC (and hooked by KVO).

That's also why `-setTimeValue:withTimeScale:` is getting away with calling `[self setMoviePosition:newMoviePosition]`, which doesn't match your `-set_moviePosition:` method. However, you should be getting a warning (and, at runtime, a crash) because you're passing a `double` to a setter which expects an `NSNumber*`.

Comment: I'm so sorry. While copy-pasting the code from Xcode, I made some minor changes and didn't fix the trial-and-error code. Please check the updated code above. Meanwhile, I'll read the Document at the link provided. Thanks so much!

Comment: The new code looks much better, but now I wonder if it reflects the situation that produced the strange behavior you're asking about. Maybe you inadvertently fixed the issue. The issues I now see: the `@synthesize` is redundant since you're providing accessor implementations. There's a backtick (\`) at the getter name. The memory management in the setter is slightly off. You don't protect against `newPos` being the same as `_moviePosition`. You should retain `newPos` before releasing `_moviePosition` or bracket the whole method with `if (newPos != _moviePosition) ...`.

Comment: Ok, fixed the memory bug and removed the @synthesize directive. Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. The NSSlider should get notified when I change the code with the accessor method and then call the setter to get the new value, right? I just don't get why this is not working.

Comment: Is there any chance you have two separate instances of the app delegate class? Perhaps one instantiated in the NIB and one instantiated in code?

Comment: No. But I just realized, that the activeMovie instance is changing every time a new movie is opened. The binding is established with KVO, right? But what happens when the observed object ( one component of the key path ) changes?

Comment: That was it! Bound the property programmatically each time a new movie got loaded and now it works. It seems that the observer is getting the observed object once when the binding is established but doesn't update it. When the setter is called, it has to get all current objects ( by going along the key path), but unfortunately it doesn't check if they all are the same that the ones being  observed. Good to know. Thanks for your help! ( Although your answer didn't really fix the issue, I will nevertheless mark it as the correct one. Maybe you want to update it a bit? )

Comment: KVO will track properly when a property along the key path changes, provided that the property was updated in a KVO-compliant manner. The fact that you have to (re)bind manually when you change `activeMovie` suggests you're not changing it in a KVO-compliant manner.

Comment: You were totally right! When I changed activeMovie, I changed the instance variable directly... thanks for shedding some light on this!